# react-native:ref props returns null

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to get the reference of the view to determine if the touch originated from the view or outside the view

```
 <View    ref={ref => { console.log("ref is",ref) }}></View>
```

I was referring https://www.jaygould.co.uk/2019-05-09-detecting-tap-outside-element-react-native/
but with this ref is always null.What am I doing wrong? How to get the reference of the element?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Class component or Functional component?

If you are using class component,try creating the ref first in constructor like this:
this.sampleDiv = React.createRef();

Then pass it to the View,

< View  ref={this.sampleDiv}> < /View >

Now you can access the DOM node using some event like click by using:
this.sampleDiv.current

If you are using functional Component try using useRef hook